# Do aldehydes give bromine water test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation

If they give bromine water test, what do they form?

I think that aldehydes will get oxidised and so decolourise bromine water but I don't know if that happens in normal conditions.

Comment: Think about how readily aldehydes enolise

Comment: Are you saying that they are quite reactive and hence might bromine water?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Br2/H2O oxidize all aldehydes?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70893/does-br2-h2o-oxidize-all-aldehydes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. Aldehydes will decolourise bromine water.

The oxidation of aldehydes to acids is discussed in this answer [Does Br2/H2O oxidize all aldehydes?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70893/does-br2-h2o-oxidize-all-aldehydes?rq=1)

In addition alpha-bromination of the aldehyde *via* the acid catalysed bromination of the enol is a well-documented process. https://chem.libretexts.org/LibreTexts/Athabasca_University/Chemistry_360%3A_Organic_Chemistry_II/Chapter_22%3A_Carbonyl_Alpha-Substitution_Reactions/22.03_Alpha_Halogenation_of_Aldehydes_and_Ketones

http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/350/Carey5th/Ch18/ch18-3-1.html