# Haloform Reaction of Furfural

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

My instructor pointed out that *furfural undergoes haloform reaction* - I don't understand how. I couldn't figure out the mechanism on my own, and couldn't find much online either. (regarding the products, or the mechanism) Could someone please help me out?

As far as I know, only methyl ketones and alcohols  oxidisable to the same undergo haloform reaction - so something unexpected must be happening here.

[image]

It'd be great if you could provide a detailed mechanism and explanation, and if possible provide sources.

Comment: Are you sure it was "furfural undergoes haloform reaction" or was it maybe "furfural undergoes reaction with haloforms"? The latter happens in methanolic KOH to give methoxy-(2-furyl)-acetic acid.

Comment: I think it's the latter, the reaction of furfural with haloforms in alkaline medium. Could you highlight the mechanism?

Comment: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01500a061?journalCode=jacsat I don't have time to draw it out, but hopefully you can just figure it out from this.

Comment: @Zhe I see no reason for it to be such kind of misunderstanding, uch more probable is a case similar to https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/96106/can-1-3-5-trihydroxybenzene-perform-haloform-reaction

Comment: @Mithoron I don't understand what you are saying. To my knowledge there's no misunderstanding on anyone's part. Maybe mishearing...

Comment: @Zhe Your paper is about synthesis and your earlier comments suggests misunderstanding on OP's part. I say furfural does react in environment used for haloform reaction, just in different way.

Comment: Related: [Does Br2/H2O oxidize all aldehydes?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70893/does-br2-h2o-oxidize-all-aldehydes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aldehydes can be oxidized by bromine under acidic conditions per the mechanism is given below.  The haloform reaction, however, occurs under basic conditions and requires a methyl ketone.  Your professor probably forgot that the haloform is for methyl ketones in basic conditions and called the reaction below a haloform even though it isn't. Given the similarity in the oxidation of the carbonyl group to a carboxylate with a halogen, (and the thousands of organic reactions to remember,) it seems like a simple easy mistake.

[image: oxidation of aldehyde with bromine]